# Abrir archivo excel (xlsm) con Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente problema, requiero abrir un archivo de excel(xlsm) con pandas y que me cree un *DataFrame* con unas de las hojas.  El archivo no se encuentra donde estoy elaborando mi `archivo.py`, es por esto que necesito que se ponga la ruta.

Estoy intentado lo siguiente:

```
file = pd.read_excel("D:\\ruben\archivos\RECEPCION\Macro Recepcion varias Carpetas2.xlsm")
print(file)
```

Sin embargo me genera el siguiente error:

> ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd

Ya intente instalando `xlrd` pero tampoco me funciona. Mil gracias a quien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: y como lo estas haciendo con `xlrd`?

Comment: Tal vez esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134031/reading-and-updating-sheets-in-an-xlsm-file-using-pandas-while-preserving-the-vb) te sirva (en ingles)

Comment: creo que deberias especificar el motor en el atributo `engine` de `pd.read_excel`, de esta forma `engine='pyxlsm'`

Comment: hola, mil gracias por responder, te cuento que el engine fue de gran ayuda, pero para mi version de python utilice engine='openpyxl'

Comment: Que bueno, si quieres puedes responder a tu propia pregunta

Answer (score 0):

El error te indica lo que ocurre:

> importError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd

La librería `xlrd` no la instala `Pandas` por defecto, si no que es opcional, y para la operación que quieres hacer se necesita, por lo tanto debes instalarla usando `pip` o `Anaconda`. Puedes por ejemplo instalarla con `pip` con el siguiente comando;

```
pip install xlrd
```

Comment: Perdona no había leido la oración final. Puedes poner el error que te da ahora, una vez instalado `xlrd` ?

Comment: hola, primero que todo muchas gracias por Responder.  ya solucione el problema no me permitia instalar el xlrd, lo que hice fue copiarlo y pegarlo en los sites-packages, y me funciono

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre la importación, la manera en que finalmente lo hice fue la siguiente

```
file = pd.read_excel(r"D:\\ruben\archivos\RECEPCION\Macro Recepcion varias Carpetas2.xlsm",sheet_name="Hoja3", engine='openpyxl')
print(file)
```

Comment: Bien echo,  puedes explicas mejor cual fue el error y como lo solucionaste?, por que es necesario especificar el `engine`? asi tu respuesta sera una respuesta completa! y obtendras votos a favor

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre la importación, el problema que estaba tendiendo era la version que tenia de pandas, buscando en la documentación de pandas encontre que engine sirve para determinar que tipo (extensión) de excel se va a subir, engine= 'xlrd', para formatos de Excel 2003, y para versiones de pandas > 1.2 el engine = 'openpyxl' y este admite archivos de extensión xlsm

```
file = pd.read_excel(r"D:\\ruben\archivos\RECEPCION\Macro Recepcion varias Carpetas2.xlsm",sheet_name="Hoja3", engine='openpyxl')
print(file)
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu respuesta, pues no es necesaria una segunda

Comment: usa el boton [edit] sobre tu respuesta original. No agregues una nueva respuesta para agregar informacion. Todo publicacion es editable en el sitio.

Comment: Si editas tu respuesta de ayer, tambien puedes aceptarla!!!!